# Can Supplier::get return null

Tags: java, java-8

The documentation of [`Supplier::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html#get--) is not explicit on the possibility or not for it to return `null`. Is it possible ?

I thought that it might be the case of a `Supplier<Void>`. In this case, how can I invoke my `Supplier` to make sure it does not result in `Supplier<Void>` ? In other word, which `T` is such such that it can be anything but `Void` ?

Comment: [Yes](https://ideone.com/SzTApr)

Comment: _why_ would it not?

Comment: `Void` would represent a lack of result. It doesn't make conceptually sense to say "I can supply you with nothing". A `Supplier<Void>` should be a `Runnable`. Returning `null` is not the same as returning nothing. It's returning something, and the something is `null`.

Comment: What you're asking is comparable to asking why a method `public String foo()` doesn't have a void return type if the string can *possibly* be null. The important distinction is that it's presumably often **not** null.

Comment: Yes it can, but not everything you can do should be done!

Comment: The question “how can I invoke my `Supplier` to make sure it does not result in `Supplier<Void>`?” makes no sense. Neither the invocation nor the returned value change the type of the `Supplier`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out by @Michael, it most certainly can, as in the following code snippet:

```java
import java.util.function.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Supplier<String> supplier = () -> null;
        System.out.println(supplier.get());
    }
}
```

It painfully highlighted my poor understanding of coping with high order usage of `Provider`.